# Double check of Book Erratum regarding Harvard Architecture and Von Neumann architecture

Tags: embedded-systems, computer-architecture

I was reading chapter 1 of the book Embedded Systems with ARM Cortex-M Microcontrollers in Assembly Language and C. (3rd Edition, June 2018)
I think the figure 1-6 is incorrect. It says that "Data memory and instruction memory are in the same memory address space in Harvard Architecture in many embedded systems."

But isn't it supposed to be Von Neumann architecture that shares the same memory address space regarding data memory and instruction memory?

Also, at the beginning of page 6, it is written that " in the Harvard Architecture, the instruction memory and the data memory are often small enough to fit in the same address space." But isn't it supposed to not be physically in the same memory hence not the same address space?

Am I missing something or is there really an erratum in the book?

Answer (score 1):

> But isn't it supposed to be Von Neumann architecture that shares the same memory address space regarding data memory and instruction memory?

No, the difference between Von Neumann and Harvard architectures is not in the address space, but in how the underlying physical memory is organized.

In a Von Neumann architecture, all memory is equal and any address can be used to store either an instruction or data.

In a Harvard architecture, there is a distinction between memory that stores instructions and memory that stores data. This distinction can be expressed with different address spaces, with the result that you can have a data-address 100 and at the same time an instruction address 100, or with a single address space where particular regions within that space are reserved for each type of memory.

Many micro controllers use a variant of the Harvard architecture, where they do not so much make a distinction between instruction memory and data memory, but rather a distinction between read-only memory (ROM or flash), used for instructions and constant data, and read-write memory (RAM), used for data that is subject to change. For ease of access to the constant data, these memory types then share a single address space.

Additionally, those micro controllers also have memory-mapped registers in that same address space for accessing IO ports, hardware timers and other features implemented in the hardware of the chip.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so it's really more of a mix between modified Harvard architecture and a bit of Von Neumann ideas. So in the books it's not pure harvard but modified harvard that the authors describe.

Comment: Yes, the book describes a modified Harvard architecture. It depends on the microcontroller if it is able to fetch and execute instructions from RAM or only from ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is general purpose, and can be used for code or data.

It is an advantage that both code & data live in the same address space, for software & programming as well as ultimately for the hardware.

Software is then free to partition available memory for either code or data as needed by the program, and different programs have different requirements, so the partitioning is dynamic.

From a very high level perspective, this appears like the Von Neuman stored-program architecture.

Most modern processors employ the use of multiple caches — at least one for code and one for data — and this is where the Harvard Architecture comes in.  Both caches can be fetching/storing simultaneously, which means the processor doesn't necessarily have to stop fetching code when a data access occurs and vice versa.  From the block diagram perspective, there is separate code memory (which is a cache) and data memory (which is also a cache).

These caches however, are both backed by a common main memory and use a shared address space, so upon a cache miss, the shared main memory is used to fill the cache, whether a code or data cache miss.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture, and the other article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture that refers to it.

A "pure" Harvard Architecture processor would be impractical as a general purpose processor, as available code memory could not be used for data and vice versa; there would be other considerations as well, but apparently they exist as microcontrollers.

Comment: Would that mean for example, that Harvard architecture could look like:

Same memory device with assigned data zone and assigned instruction zone. 
And there would be two buses connected to that same memory device for concurrent access to instruction and data?

Comment: It would be possible to dual port main memory (two busses) so that it can respond to data and code requests, but this is better done by having completely separate code & data caches.  To add to that, the concept of code vs. data cache vs. main memory is already a simplification, as today they have L1, L2, L3 caches, where some of those lower-numbered levels are separated (harvard) and some higher numbered are unified (von neuman).

Comment: Harvard architectures are alive and kicking (e.g. AVR microcontrollers - can only run code from code memory - internal flash, can't run code from RAM, don't have caches).